# Calling Accounts.createUser in Meteor app Iron-Router endpoint is giving net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: jquery, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I have a **Meteor** app that has its client-side js make a jQuery ajax `GET` call to my apps exposed API (implemented server side with Iron-Router).

**Client side:**

```
$.get('email/test@test.com/transaction/?transactionId=12344', function (data) { console.log(data); });
```

**Server API side:**

```
Router.route('/email/:email/transaction',{where: 'server'})
            .get(function(){
                let email = this.params.email;
                let transactionId = this.params.query.transactionId;
                if(email === undefined) {
                    let response = { "error" : true, "message" : "Email required" };
                    this.response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    this.response.statusCode = 403;
                    this.response.end(JSON.stringify(response));
                    return;
                }

                // Create the user
                let user = Accounts.findUserByEmail(email);
                if(user === undefined) {
                    Accounts.createUser({
                        email: email,
                        password: transactionId,
                        username: email,
                        profile: {
                            "transactionId" : [{transactionId: transactionId, date: moment(new Date())}]
                        }
                    });

                    this.response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    this.response.statusCode = 200;
                    this.response.end(JSON.stringify({"created": true}));

                }
                else {
                    this.response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    this.response.statusCode = 200;
                    this.response.end(JSON.stringify({"created": false}));
                }

            });
```

When run **locally** - *on localhost:3000* - this works great! The endpoint is called, and the account is created, and a 200 response code is returned.

**However**, when deployed to my hosting server, the endpoint is failing with `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. By trial and error, I have found that removing the `Accounts.createUser(...)` code makes the endpoint respond correctly, however - of course - there is no user created.

**Does anyone know why the `Accounts.createUser(...)` would force the endpoint to yield an empty response? (`net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`)**

Its very odd to me that it works locally, however, if I can just figure out how to get it to create a user on my deployed server, I don't care why there is a difference.